# Using If Statements in ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I've never used Python scripting before and can't seem to figure out how to use an If statement in the Field Calculator tool.

I have a field called 'MAX_GRIDCODE' which returns the highest force a piece of infrastructure is exposed to. I need to use this number to calculate a simple estimate of damage in the field 'DI'.

The statements I need are:

```
If "Max_GRIDCODE" >0 and <=0.5 then "DI" = 1
If "Max_GRIDCODE" >0.5 and <=1 then "DI" = 2
If "Max_GRIDCODE" >1 and <=1.5 then "DI" = 3
If "Max_GRIDCODE" >1.5 and <=2 then "DI" = 4
If "Max_GRIDCODE" >2 then "DI" = 5
```

How do I code this using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open CalculateField tool

for 'Field Name' parameter specify: DI

for 'Expression' parameter specify: x(!Max_GRIDCODE!)

for 'Code Block' parameter specify the code below

```
def x(v):
    if v > 2:     return 5
    elif v > 1.5: return 4
    elif v > 1:   return 3
    elif v > 0.5:  return 2
    else: return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Esri Support provide an [How To: Use IF statements in the Field Calculator](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022370):

> **Summary**
>
> The Field Calculator uses IF statements to calculate new values in the
> field of an attribute table. This article describes some common uses
> of IF statements in the Field Calculator and with Python scripts.